# Call gcc builtin in cython?

Tags: c, gcc, cython

I want to call the [gcc builtin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) function `__builtin_ffs` inside a cython sourcefile (`.pyx`), e.g. like

```
cpdef int ffs(long b):
    return __builtin_ffs(b);
```

Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply declare the builtin as if it were an external function  (http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/external_C_code.html)

```
cdef extern int __builtin_ffs(unsigned int x)
```

Since `__builtin_ffs` does not appear in any header file, it is not necessary to use the `extern from "header.h"` construct. Needless to say, the module will only build using a compiler that knows about `__builtin_ffs`.